# Update ListView after set new Value in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem to set a new value in my ListView after  I saved it in the sharedPreferences.

[image: The two lines - ListView with Items]

On the picture you can see what I can see on my smartphone screen (easier to describe for me). If I press now the Item "Korrektur-Faktor" an AlertDialog opens and i can set a new Value.

[image: The AlertDialog]

If I now press save the new value (80) will be saved in the SharedPreferences but the value in the second Line of my ListViewItem will not be automatically updated.

Here some code:

```
    String secLineCorrect = correctvalue.toString();
    ValueSettings targetValue = new ValueSettings("Zielwert", "getTargetSharedPref"); //TODO
    ValueSettings correctFactor = new ValueSettings("Korrektur-Faktor", secLineCorrect + " mg/dl pro 1IE");

    //Füllen der ListView
    final ArrayList<ValueSettings> valuesSettingsList = new ArrayList<>();
    valuesSettingsList.add(targetValue);
    valuesSettingsList.add(correctFactor);

    final ValueSettingsListAdapter valuesSettingsAdapter = new ValueSettingsListAdapter(this, R.layout.settings_list_item_two_lines, valuesSettingsList);
    lvValues.setAdapter(valuesSettingsAdapter);

    //Klickbare Items
    lvValues.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(position){
                    //First Item in List
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "You clicked on: " + valuesSettingsList.get(position).getFirstLine() +  "mit Item Nummer" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                    //Second Item in List
                case 1:
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_correctfactor,null);
                    final EditText mCorrectFactor = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.et_correct_factor_input);
                    Button mCancel = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
                    Button mSave = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                    //Click on Cancel
                    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Abgebrochen. Kein neuer Wert eingespeichert!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    //Click on Save
                    mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if(mCorrectFactor.getText().length() > 0){
                                correctvalue = Integer.parseInt(mCorrectFactor.getText().toString());
                                editor.putInt(correctValueKEY, correctvalue);
                                editor.commit();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 IE entspricht " + correctvalue + " mg/dl.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wert ist auf " + correctvalue + " md/dl gesetzt. Keine Änderung vorgenommen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });


                    break;

            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see I set the text in the beginning of the code. So every time I want that the new value I saved before is shown up, I have to go back into my main-Activity and start the settings-Activity new. But now I want that after i pressed save and the AlertDialog is closed, the new value is shown. I tried so much but never get a solution. 
May someone can help me out :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure the saved value is reflected in the `valuesSettingsList`,  as suggested by woodii.

You can then add this line after you save the new value:

```
valuesSettingsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I can but it does not change something :) oh i don't saw the comment from wood before ... i will try :)

Answer (score 1):

For such features i can suggest `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity`.
Anyway you can use `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and override the method `onSharedPreferenceChanged` and update the Entry in the list accordingly.

Currently you only change the stored value in the `SharedPreferences` but not the visible value in the List.

Comment: what do I write into the onSharedPreferenceChanged-method?

Comment: Update the values in your `valuesSettingsList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` afterwards to refresh the view.